# How to receive a list in jQuery from Django(Python)

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm send a list from Django(Python) to jQuery, but it is throwing some error while receiving it?

Here is what I send in python.

```
hubcode_list = ['a','b']
ctx = {'form':form, 'hubcode_list' : hubcode_list, 'admin_permission' : admin_permission}
return render(request, 'dummy/config.html', ctx)
```

jQuery:-

```
var hubcode_list = {{ hubcode_list }}
```

It returns an error saying :-

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
var hubcode_list = [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;]
```

When I use `escapejs` as

```
var hubcode_list = {{ hubcode_list|escapejs }}
```

it throws

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
var hubcode_list = [\u0027a\u0027, \u0027b\u0027]
```

How do I receive a list from server(Python)? I need to implement an autocomplete functionality where I need to pass a list of tags.

```
$( ".hubcode_list" ).autocomplete({
        source: hubcode_list
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hubcode_list = [str(i) for i in hubcode_list]  #unicode string not understood by javascript
{{ hubcode_list|safe }}
```

The good way is to pass `json`.

```
>>> import json
>>> hubcode_list = ['a','b']
>>> json.dumps(hubcode_list)
>>> '["a", "b"]'
```

**jQuery:**

```
var hubcode_list = JSON.parse(hubcode_list)
```

If you want to implement `jquery Autocomplete`, you should implement it via `AJAX`. **You shouldn't pass all the autocomplete at once. What if there are thousands of data?** See [this tutorial](http://www.linuxislife.com/python/django-tutorial/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-django/) on how to implement jquery autocomplete with Django.

Comment: Throws the following error `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list 
var hubcode_list = [u'KOLS', u'ASN']`

Comment: Now this error. `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

var hubcode_list = JSON.parse(hubcode_list)`

Comment: But I just dump `hubcode_list` not everything. ie, `hubcode_list = json.dumps(['a','b'])
 ctx = {'form':form, 'hubcode_list' : hubcode_list, 'admin_permission' : admin_permission}
 return render(request, 'dummy/config.html', ctx)`

Comment: Your second comment shows the `JSON` is invalid. What is the actual data on `hubcode_list` variable.

Comment: Actual data is `['ASN','MUM','DEL']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeString

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeString
...
return render(request, 'dummy/config.html', {'ctx': SafeString(ctx)})
```

But ctx needs to be a valid json format variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like:

```
import json
ctx = {'form':form, 'hubcode_list' : hubcode_list, 'hubcode_json': json.dumps(hubcode_list), 'admin_permission' : admin_permission}
return render(request, 'dummy/config.html', ctx)
```

In your jQuery you can do something like

```
var parsed_json = eval("({{ hubcode_json }})");
```

or

```
var parsed_json = $.parseJSON("{{ hubcode_json }}");
```

Ok, is not the cleanest way but it works, at least, for me.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Why to convert the whole context to `json`?

Comment: Says syntax error. Dont know why? `SyntaxError: syntax error
 

([&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;])

 
`

Comment: `eval` is `evil`. That's not the way to parse the json. Only use `eval` if you completely trust your data.

Comment: I normally trust my data when it goes to a template, my server part takes care about it ;) we are not talking about security, just about json right? :) anyway U can use something like $.parseJSON("{{ hubcode_json }}")

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers are on the right track, but aren't clear enough.

To pass data from Python to Javascript, use JSON.

```
hubcode_list = json.dumps(['a','b'])
```

Comment: I tried but i keep getting different errors. Dont know the correct way of doing it. I tried with your code as well.